# Setting values in openpyxl load_workbook, use_iterators

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to read a xlsx file, change all the values less than say 0.0001 to 0.01. I can read the values and print them, but I can't change them ?

```
import pylab

from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'TF-Automation.xlsx', use_iterators=True)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Huvudmatris')

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.internal_value < 0.00001:
              cell.set_value = 0.000001      
        print cell.internal_value
```

Comment: Because this is the first result via google... if you are using openpyxl > 2.4.0 and getting an error related to the use_iterators argument... it's been changed to read_only in current release.  Ref: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/changes.html?highlight=iterators#id74

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation : http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/api.html

```
 openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename,use_iterators=False)[source] :
```

> ```
> Open the given filename and return the workbook
> Parameters:   
>
>     filename (string) – the path to open
>     use_iterators (bool) – use lazy load for cells
>
> Return type:  
>     openpyxl.workbook.Workbook
> ```
>
> When using lazy load, all worksheets will be
>   `openpyxl.reader.iter_worksheet.IterableWorksheet` and **the returned
>   workbook will be read-only.**

don't use `use_iterators=True` . Also, if you need to call `.save(filename)` if you want to update the xlsx with your new values.